# Global/Persistent UIBarButtonItem like Twitter's Compose Button?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` with alot of `viewControllers`, and I want to add a `UIBarButtonItem` to the top-right. I did that, but I have to do this individually to each view controller. What's the best pattern to add it once and have it stay there throughout the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can create a global function like in appDelegate and pass some parameters on that function. Like pass your navigationController,target,selector.

Here is sample code snippet.

```
- (UIBarbuttonItem *) rightBarButtonGlobal:(UINavigationItem*)navigationItem target:(id)target {
  //you can also pass nsstring for title and selector for you desired selector.
  //But as per your question I assume you want a application logo like button in navigation bar. If that is the case just pass navigationItem as parameter.Create your logo button and assign to navigationItem.
  //Allocate button here
  navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
  [button release];
}
```